# JPA setting UUID as query parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting issues in executing `delete query` using `JPA`.

The problem is that I am deleting a row based on UUID.

To accomplish delete task, I set the `UUID` parameter in JPA query `setParameter` method. But this fails giving `CAST` issues.

So I used the following:

```
query.setParameter("fileUuid", String.class.cast(fileUuid));
```

But again it gave exception.

Here is the code--

Entity Class:

```
@Id
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen")
@Column(name = "file_uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID fileUuid;
```

Manager Class:

```
@Override
public void deleteFile(UUID fileUuid) {
    final String ql = "delete from " + type.getName() + "  
    where file_uuid = :fileUuid";
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(ql);
    query.setParameter("fileUuid", 
    String.class.cast(fileUuid));
    try {
        query.executeUpdate();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Exception Log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.UUID to java.lang.String
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
```

UPDATE:

These are the dependencies in my pom.xml-

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What Hibernate Version do you use?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli. hibernate version `4.3.11.Final`. See update.

Comment: Have you tried using `fileUuid.toString()` instead of `String.class.cast(fileUuid)`

Comment: Why don't yo just pass fileUuid as the parameter? Why do you try casting it to a String? And why don't you just use em.remove(em.getReference(...))?

Comment: @cdaiga- yes I tried using `fileUuid.toString()` in the beginning but it was giving some cast exception. So I did cast but that also didn't resolved issue.

Comment: @JBNizet. That `fileUuid` as a parameter is not working. So the only thing that I didn't tried was your `em.remove`. I just tried it and it worked. :)

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Note that your field is named `fileUuid`, not `file_uuid` as you're incorrectly using in your query.

Comment: @JBNizet. Ok to answer you question. I will again change the code and just pass fileUuid then re-compile and run and then put exception trace for you.

Comment: @JBNizet- When I just pass fileUuid as a parameter, it gives exception saying that `ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bytea`.  `Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 0):

Using `super.removeById` is the working solution-

```
@Override
public void deleteFile(UUID fileUuid) {
    T entity =getEntityManager().find(type, id)
    if (entity != null) {
      getEntityManager().remove(entity);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Why? Why do you use a query to find an entity by ID, and especially one you want to delete anyway? Why don't you use em.getReference(), or em.find() if you really want to check that the entity exists before deleting it? And why do you still try to delete the entity if it couldn't be found?

Comment: @JBNizet. I used query to find an entity by ID because `remove` takes entity. However, whatever you pointed out is interesting which I wasn't aware of. Let me try that and then I will come up with result. :)

Comment: @JBNizet. After digging in more, I came up with a good working solution. See my updated answer and if you still disagree (or still prefer  `em.getReference()`, or `em.find()`) then let me know as I don't really know the significance of it over my solution.

Comment: I have no idea what `super` is. But sure, if you already have a method removeById(), use it. Not sure why you have a deleteFile() method doing the same thing as removeById(), though. And this of course doesn't really answer your original question.

Comment: @JBNizet. `super` : I have a Non-generic base class for all entity managers that has `removeById` method. So my entity class is extending this base class. So I used `super`. The method `removeById` is calling `em.find()` and then `em.remove(entity)` that is defined in base class. So indirectly it is using same thing that you mentioned earlier. My bad :(

Comment: I just updated my answer back so that all will understand the actual flow. Otherwise `removeById` method behind the scenes will not reveal anything to anyone. :)